# Prove $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$ and $\int_{-2}^{2} f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(0)= 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ for $x \in [-2,2] \setminus \{0\}$. Using the definition of the Riemann integral and Riemann condition for integrabilty, prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$ and $\int_{-2}^{2} f = 0$

I was given a solution but there are parts I dont understand and perhaps there is a more explanatory approach.

**proof**

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }x=0 \\
x/|x|, & \text{if } x\in[-2,2] \setminus \{0\} 
\end{cases}$

$P_n = \{-2, \frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, 2 \}$ * I dont understand how this sequence corresponds to the problem or how it is created.

$\bar{S}(f,P_n) = (-1)(\frac{-1}{n} - (-2)) + (1)(\frac{2}{n}) + (1)(2 - \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{2}{n}$ * Not sure how $-1$ or $1$ corresponds to supremum or the $\Delta{x_i}$ or for example $(\frac{-1}{n} - (-2))$ is supposed to be the supremeum between $[-2, \frac{-1}{n}]$

$\underline{S}(f,P_n) = (-1)(\frac{-1}{n} - (-2)) + (-1)(\frac{2}{n}) + (1)(2 - \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{-2}{n}$

$\bar{S}(f,P_n) - \underline{S}(f,P_n) = \frac{4}{n} \rightarrow 0$

*It seems like positive proof but I cant understand the reasoning or scratch work needed to explain my confusion.

Comment: The $P_n$ is the partition. As far as 1 or -1 being the sup, what does $\frac{x}{|x|}$ equal when $x\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,2]$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x\in[-2,0)$.

Since you say you're required to use the definition of Riemann integral, you need to look at the one you've been  given, which is doubtless in terms of partitions.  The usual ones are Baby Rudin's (6.2, sup of lower sums equals inf of upper sums) or else upper and lower sums converging to each other as a sequence of partitions becomes finer (the theorem of Baby Rudin 6.6 used as a definition).

To take your comments one by one:

- I don't understand how this sequence corresponds to the problem or how it is created.

Partitions are relevant to the Riemann integral.  In proving that something is Riemann integrable with a definition using limits of upper and lower sums, you are allowed to pick whatever sequence of partitions works for you and causes the difference between upper and lower sums to converge to zero.

- Not sure how $−1$ or $1$ corresponds to supremum or the $Δx_i$ or for example $({−1\over n}−(−2))$ is supposed to be the supremum between $[−2,{−1\over n}]$

As regards $-1$ and $1$, see first sentence of this answer.  $({−1\over n}−(−2))$ is not the supremum but rather the length of $[-2,1/n)$.

- It seems like positive proof but I can't understand the reasoning

The goal is to find partitions $P_n$ that produce upper and lower sums whose difference converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  The last line of the proof shows they've accomplished this and thus shown that the function is Riemann integrable.